# python: how to use logistic regression coefficients to construct decision boundary in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to do more all within sklearn. Here I am trying to generate an unbalanced classification set, run a logistic regression, plot the data points and plot a decision boundary line.

In order to plot the decision boundary line, I first get the coefficients:

```
coef = clf.best_estimator_.coef_
intercept = clf.best_estimator_.intercept_
```

And then I construct the line:

```
x1 = np.linspace(-8, 10, 100)
x2 = -(coef[0][0] * x1 + intercept[0]) / coef[0][1]
plt.plot(x1, x2, color='#414e8a', linewidth=2)
```

However, the line doesn't plot because x2 is all inf because coef[0][1] is equal to 0. This is the problem that I am having. Why is the second term of these coefficients 0?

Full code below:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold, train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
%pylab inline
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12, 6)
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))

# Generate data with two classes
X, y = make_classification(class_sep=1.2, weights=[0.1, 0.9], n_informative=3, n_redundant=1, n_features=5, n_clusters_per_class=1, n_samples=10000, flip_y=0, random_state=10)
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
X = pca.fit_transform(X)

y = y.astype('str')
y[y=='1'] ='L'
y[y=='0'] ='S'

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.7, random_state=0)

X_1, X_2 = X_train[y_train=='S'], X_train[y_train=='L']

# Fit a Logistic Regression model
clf_base = LogisticRegression()
grid = {'C': 10.0 ** np.arange(-2, 3),'penalty': ['l1', 'l2']}
cv = KFold(X_train.shape[0], n_folds=5, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
clf = GridSearchCV(clf_base, grid, cv=cv, n_jobs=8, scoring='f1_macro')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Get coefficients
coef = clf.best_estimator_.coef_
intercept = clf.best_estimator_.intercept_

# Create separation line
x1 = np.linspace(-8, 10, 100)
x2 = -(coef[0][0] * x1 + intercept[0]) / coef[0][1]

plt.scatter(X_1[:,0], X_1[:,1], color='#1abc9c')
plt.scatter(X_2[:,0], X_2[:,1], color='#e67e22')
x_coords = np.concatenate([X_1[:,0],X_2[:,0]])
y_coords = np.concatenate([X_1[:,1],X_2[:,1]])
plt.axis([min(x_coords), max(x_coords), min(y_coords), max(y_coords)])
plt.title("Original Dataset - Fitted Logistic Regression")
plt.plot(x1, x2, color='#414e8a', linewidth=2)
plt.show()

print(coef)
```

As you can see the second term in coef is 0.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

EDIT

It seems like the grid search parameters is leading to the second coefficient being zero. For example:

When I set the grid parameter to:

```
grid = {'C': 10.0 ** np.arange(-2, 3),'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],'class_weight': ['balanced']}
```

This gives me two non-zero coeficients

When I remove the class weight parameter:

```
grid = {'C': 10.0 ** np.arange(-2, 3),'penalty': ['l1', 'l2']}
```

This gives me a zero for the second element in coef.

Hope that simplifies the problem. Anyone out there have an idea? Thank you!

Comment: logistic regression

Comment: I don't follow?

Answer (score 0):

You got zero first coefficient, because you use **strong L1 regularization**, which removes all the not-so-useful features from the model.

You can see it with `clf.best_params_` - it equals `{'C': 0.01, 'penalty': 'l1'}`. Switch to 'l2' penalty, and you will have all coefficients non-zero.

If you want to plot an arbitrary line of form `Ax+By+C=0`, you can use this function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_normal_line(A, B, C, ax=None, **kwargs):
    """ Plot equation of Ax+By+C=0"""
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    if A == 0 and B == 0:
        raise Exception('A or B should be non-zero')
    if B == 0:
        # plot vertical
        ax.vlines(-C / A, *ax.get_ylim(), **kwargs)
    else:
        # plot functoon
        x = np.array(ax.get_xlim())
        y = (A*x+C) / -B
        ax.plot(x, y, **kwargs)
```

Then the command `plot_normal_line(*coef[0], intercept)` will draw your decision boundary.

However, since your dataset is balanced, for nearly all the points the most probable class is the second one (the orange). So the decision boundary for 50% probability (the thick black line) lies at the left from the scatter:

[image]